# Counting booleans in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary object that contains a boolean for every key, e.g.:

```
d = {'client1': True, 'client2': False}
```

What is the easiest and most concise way to count the number of True values in the dictionary?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For clarity:

```
num_true = sum(1 for condition in d.values() if condition)
```

For conciseness (this works because True is a subclass of int with a value 1):

```
num_true = sum(d.values())
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sum(d.values())
```

Comment: Simple and general, one only has to know that booleans are also integers in Python, and specifically 0 and 1 (not surprisingly).

Comment: that's what docs are for: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values

Answer (score 3):

```
a.values().count(True)
```

Comment: clear, but not as clear as using `sum()` IMO. Will stop working when Python 3's `dict.values` returns an interable view, not a list.

Comment: how is it not as clear as using "sum"? it reads "count the number of elements in values() whose value is True"; it is a direct translation of the problem whereas sum() introduces one level of conceptual indirection.

Comment: actually this is more english than using true as a number.

Answer (score 1):

In Python `2.*`, sum(d.itervalues()) is slightly less concise than the `sum(d.values())` many are proposing (4 more characters;-), but avoids needlessly materializing the list of values and so saves memory (and probably time) when you have a large dictionary to deal with.

As some have pointed out, this works fine, because bools are ints (a subclass, specifically):

```
>>> False==0
True
>>> False+True
1
```

therefore, no need for circumlocutory `if` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is you have to convert the dict_values into list and use `count()`

```
d = {'client1': True, 'client2': False}
list(d.values()).count(True)
```

Ans will be: `1`